# Return an error message from Flask and handle it on JavaScript after an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, python-3.x, flask

So I have a Python backend done with Flask:

```
@app.route('/test/')
def test():
    data = get_database_data(request.args.id)  # Returns dict of data, or None
    if data is None:
        # What do I do here?
    return jsonify(data)
```

And I now make an AJAX request with JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("/test/", {id: 5}, function(data) {
        // What do I do here?
    });
});
```

I want to call `handleData(data)` on JS side if it returns proper data, but how do I return an error and handle it on JS side to avoid trying to handle the error with `handleData()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flask.abort` to exit the controller with an error code (a message). See: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors

The classic error code can be **400** Bad Request. If you have a REST API, you can choose an error code here [HTTP Status Codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html). *see codes with asterisk*.

From the client side, you handle this error with the `jQuery.ajax()` function. There is an "error" callback. See: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/